# Installed Gnome but I don't want gnome 3

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I installed gnome because I liked the old gnome, but I installed Gnome 3, and even when I go into gnome classic, I can't right click the top and bottom bars and customize them like I used to do in Ver 11 (or 10... I'm not exactly sure... but it wasn't 12) of Ubuntu. Anyway to revert back?

I'm in 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in GNOME Classic session which uses `compiz` for effects. Compiz disabled those options. To add the icons do the following

1. Login to "Gnome-Classic (No effect)" session
2. Press and Hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd>
3. While holding Alt key, right click on the top panel
4. Select "Add to panel"
5. Choose "Application launcher"
6. Click on the "Forward" button at the bottom.
7. Select the desired application icon from the list. You can add a complete category such as "Sound & Video" to the panel!
8. Click "Add" button or double click the Application entry.

You're done. Now login again to Gnome-Classic (with effect) session. It should now include the icons in top panel.

Comment: I answered the question because, I think he wanted to customize the top and bottom panel which can't be done with "Gnome-Classic" session which uses compiz.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but I went in and actually tried it and it didn't work. Right clicking doesn't give me the option.

Comment: @EGHDK See the updated answer

Comment: I'll mark you as the correct answer, but for me all I had to do was hold the alt and super key while right clicking. Then I was able to do everything as I expected.

Comment: I hold the alt key and right click, don't required the super key. anyway glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) or [Mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_%28desktop_environment%29) desktop environments.

Comment: Mate (gnome 2 fork), not cinnamon (gnome 3 fork).